# How to get sum of comma separated values returned by GROUP_CONCAT(if(type = 'tax',amount,NULL)) AS 'tax'

Tags: mysql, sum

```
GROUP_CONCAT(if(type = 'tax',amount,NULL)) AS 'tax'
```

When i use this in query it returns a comma separated values like

```
53.00,42.34
```

I wanted retrieve this value as a sum. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please let me know if my answer works. It may not be the best option in case you also need other columns from the FROM clause.

Comment: thank u @DhruvJoshi u saved lot of my manual work... it worked fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use something like

```
SUM(if(type = 'tax',amount,NULL)) AS 'tax'
```